# Html text and image side by side

Tags: html, css

This is a piece of my code I would like to know how to put an image and paragraph side by side.

```
    <section class="contact-section" id="contact">
    <div class="container">
         <h1>All About Us</h1>
         <hr>
         <img src="hpbanner.webp" width="600" height="750">
         <p>text here</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you include the css you are trying to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap img and p in a div, and make it a flexbox.

```css
.flex-class {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;  /* this is optional because row is default*/
  align-items: center;  /* this is if you want to align items vertically in the center */
}
```

```html
<section class="contact-section" id="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>All About Us</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="flex-class">
      <img src="hpbanner.webp" width="600" height="750">
      <p>text here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @Sfili_81 - thanks for the edit, is there any guide I can refer to which talks about the best practices/guidelines to writing better answers on SO?

Comment: HI, i think think can help you [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)